# Path integral for free fermion: meaning of boundary terms

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, fermions

In article [Deriving Projective Hyperspace from Harmonic](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.3588) there is discussion of JWKB (page 7) path integral for free fermion.

Here I briefly rederive the statement:

If one start with Lagrangian:
$$
L = \bar{\psi}\dot{\psi}
$$

And perform path integration through discretisation ($t_1-t_0 = N\epsilon$):

$$
Z = \int D\psi D \bar{\psi} \;e^{iS[\psi, \bar{\phi}]} 
=
\int D\psi D \bar{\psi} \;e^{i \int^{t_1}_{t_0}\bar{\psi}\dot{\psi}}
=
\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod^{N-1}_{k=1}\int  d\psi_k d \bar{\psi}_k \;e^{i \sum^{N}_{k=1}\bar{\psi}_k\frac{\psi_k - \psi_{k-1}}{\epsilon} \epsilon} 
$$

$$
Z
\propto
\lim_{N\to\infty}\prod^{N-1}_{k=1}\int  d\psi_k \; \delta(\psi_k - \psi_{k-1}) e^{i \bar{\psi}_N(\psi_N - \psi_{N-1})}
\propto 
e^{i \bar{\psi}_N(\psi_N - \psi_{0})}
$$

If one revisit derivation of [Path integrals for fermions](http://www-th.bo.infn.it/people/bastianelli/ch3-FT2.pdf) (see part 3), one need take away $i \bar{\psi}_N\psi_N$. So finally we have:

$$
Z \propto e^{- i \bar{\psi}_N \psi_{0}}
$$

What is the meaning of obtained answer? How to interpret the result?

Comment: You should not remove $i\bar\psi_N\psi_N$! It needs to be here (it is there during the construction of the path integral). However, you should recall that $\psi_0 \equiv \psi_N$ by construction.

Comment: @Adam, why $\psi_0 = \psi_N$ by construction?

Comment: See Eq. 70 and below from your reference (where to get the partition function, you need to put $\bar\psi_f=\bar\psi_N$ and $\psi_i=\psi_0=\psi_N$ and integrate over both.